# SSIS Deployed Package Error

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, ssis

Hoping someone can help me with this.

I have created a very simple SSIS package in Visual Studio that copies data from an MSSQL table, converts the data, and inserts the data into a MySQL 5.5 database table.  When I run the package in Visual Studio it works prefectly.

However, when I build the package and then deploy it to MSSQL 2014 Integration Services and try to execute the package it fails.

Here is the report that MSSQL creates on fail:

> This report displays messages for the executions or validations.

```
    Execution Information


    Operation ID    88 (Validation)
```

Name    PurchaseAnalysisReport\PurchasingAnalysis\Package.dtsx
Environment -
Status  Failed
        Duration (sec)  7.875
Start Time  12/10/2016 12:59:30 PM
End Time    12/10/2016 12:59:38 PM
Caller  **********************

```
    Error Messages


        Message Type    Action  Message Time    Message Message Source Name Subcomponent Name   Execution Path  Environment
OnError View Context    12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS:Error: One or more component failed validation.
EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS    SSIS.Pipeline   \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS   -
OnError View Context    12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS:Error: There were errors during task validation.
EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS        \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS   -
OnError View Context    12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS:Error: The version of ODBC Destination, clsid {51B271F1-3B7E-4875-870E-62A0456FE2AD} is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS    SSIS.Pipeline   \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS   -
OnError View Context    12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS:Error: The version of ODBC Source, clsid {F8600F4A-E321-42F4-AA59-DA00FA374EA5} is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS    SSIS.Pipeline   \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS   -
OnError View Context    12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS:Error: The component is missing, not registered, not upgradeable, or missing required interfaces. The contact information for this component is "ODBC Destination;Connector for Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) by Attunity; Attunity Ltd.; All Rights Reserved; http://www.attunity.com;6".
EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS    ODBC Destination [8]    \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS   -
OnError View Context    12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS:Error: ODBC Destination failed validation and returned error code 0xC0048021.
EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS    SSIS.Pipeline   \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS   -
OnError View Context    12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOC_INFO:Error: The version of ODBC Destination is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOC_INFO   EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOC_INFO (SSIS.Pipeline)   \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOC_INFO  -
OnError View Context    12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOC_INFO:Error: The version of ODBC Source is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOC_INFO   EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOC_INFO (SSIS.Pipeline)   \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOC_INFO  -
OnError View Context    12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOCATIONS:Error: The version of ODBC Destination is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOCATIONS  EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOCATIONS (SSIS.Pipeline)  \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOCATIONS -
OnError View Context    12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOCATIONS:Error: The version of ODBC Source is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOCATIONS  EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOCATIONS (SSIS.Pipeline)  \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOCATIONS -
OnError View Context    12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_LINES:Error: The version of ODBC Destination is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_LINES   EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_LINES (SSIS.Pipeline)   \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_LINES  -
OnError View Context    12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_LINES:Error: The version of ODBC Source is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_LINES   EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_LINES (SSIS.Pipeline)   \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_LINES  -
OnError View Context    12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_HDR:Error: The version of ODBC Destination is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_HDR EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_HDR (SSIS.Pipeline) \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_HDR    -
OnError View Context    12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_HDR:Error: The version of ODBC Source is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_HDR EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_HDR (SSIS.Pipeline) \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_HDR    -
OnError View Context    12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_LINES:Error: The version of ODBC Destination is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_LINES  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_LINES (SSIS.Pipeline)  \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_LINES -
OnError View Context    12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_LINES:Error: The version of ODBC Source is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_LINES  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_LINES (SSIS.Pipeline)  \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_LINES -
OnError View Context    12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_COSTS:Error: The version of ODBC Destination is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_COSTS  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_COSTS (SSIS.Pipeline)  \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_COSTS -
OnError View Context    12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_COSTS:Error: The version of ODBC Source is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_COSTS  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_COSTS (SSIS.Pipeline)  \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_COSTS -
OnError View Context    12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS:Error: The version of ODBC Source is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS    EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS (SSIS.Pipeline)    \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS   -
OnError View Context    12/10/2016 12:59:35 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS:Error: The version of ODBC Destination is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS    EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS (SSIS.Pipeline)    \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS   -


    All Messages


            Filter:

Message Type: All;  (5 more)





        Message Type    Message Time    Message Message Source Name Subcomponent Name   Execution Path  Environment
OnInformation   12/10/2016 12:59:38 PM  The validate operation has completed.   Transact-SQL stored procedure           -
OnError 12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS:Error: One or more component failed validation.
EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS    SSIS.Pipeline   \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS   -
OnError 12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS:Error: There were errors during task validation.
EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS        \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS   -
OnPostValidate  12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS:Validation is complete.    EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS        \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS   -
OnPostValidate  12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  Package:Validation is complete. Package     \Package    -
OnError 12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS:Error: The version of ODBC Destination, clsid {51B271F1-3B7E-4875-870E-62A0456FE2AD} is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS    SSIS.Pipeline   \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS   -
OnError 12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS:Error: The version of ODBC Source, clsid {F8600F4A-E321-42F4-AA59-DA00FA374EA5} is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS    SSIS.Pipeline   \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS   -
OnInformation   12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS:Information: Validation phase is beginning.
EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS    SSIS.Pipeline   \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS   -
OnError 12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS:Error: The component is missing, not registered, not upgradeable, or missing required interfaces. The contact information for this component is "ODBC Destination;Connector for Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) by Attunity; Attunity Ltd.; All Rights Reserved; http://www.attunity.com;6".
EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS    ODBC Destination [8]    \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS   -
OnError 12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS:Error: ODBC Destination failed validation and returned error code 0xC0048021.
EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS    SSIS.Pipeline   \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS   -
OnPostValidate  12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  DELETE DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS:Validation is complete.    DELETE DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS        \Package\DELETE DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS   -
OnPreValidate   12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  DELETE DATA_WH STOCK_LOC_INFO:Validation has started.   DELETE DATA_WH STOCK_LOC_INFO       \Package\DELETE DATA_WH STOCK_LOC_INFO  -
OnPostValidate  12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  DELETE DATA_WH STOCK_LOC_INFO:Validation is complete.   DELETE DATA_WH STOCK_LOC_INFO       \Package\DELETE DATA_WH STOCK_LOC_INFO  -
OnPreValidate   12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  DELETE DATA_WH STOCK_LOCATIONS:Validation has started.  DELETE DATA_WH STOCK_LOCATIONS      \Package\DELETE DATA_WH STOCK_LOCATIONS -
OnPostValidate  12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  DELETE DATA_WH STOCK_LOCATIONS:Validation is complete.  DELETE DATA_WH STOCK_LOCATIONS      \Package\DELETE DATA_WH STOCK_LOCATIONS -
OnPreValidate   12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  DELETE FROM DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_COSTS:Validation has started. DELETE FROM DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_COSTS     \Package\DELETE FROM DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_COSTS    -
OnPostValidate  12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  DELETE FROM DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_COSTS:Validation is complete. DELETE FROM DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_COSTS     \Package\DELETE FROM DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_COSTS    -
OnPreValidate   12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  DELETE FROM DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_LINES:Validation has started. DELETE FROM DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_LINES     \Package\DELETE FROM DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_LINES    -
OnPostValidate  12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  DELETE FROM DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_LINES:Validation is complete. DELETE FROM DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_LINES     \Package\DELETE FROM DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_LINES    -
OnPreValidate   12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  DELETE FROM DATA_WH PURCHORD_HDR:Validation has started.    DELETE FROM DATA_WH PURCHORD_HDR        \Package\DELETE FROM DATA_WH PURCHORD_HDR   -
OnPostValidate  12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  DELETE FROM DATA_WH PURCHORD_HDR:Validation is complete.    DELETE FROM DATA_WH PURCHORD_HDR        \Package\DELETE FROM DATA_WH PURCHORD_HDR   -
OnPreValidate   12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  DELETE FROM DATA_WH PURCHORD_LINES:Validation has started.  DELETE FROM DATA_WH PURCHORD_LINES      \Package\DELETE FROM DATA_WH PURCHORD_LINES -
OnPostValidate  12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  DELETE FROM DATA_WH PURCHORD_LINES:Validation is complete.  DELETE FROM DATA_WH PURCHORD_LINES      \Package\DELETE FROM DATA_WH PURCHORD_LINES -
OnPreValidate   12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS:Validation has started.    EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS        \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS   -
OnPreValidate   12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  Package:Validation has started. Package     \Package    -
OnPreValidate   12/10/2016 12:59:37 PM  DELETE DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS:Validation has started.    DELETE DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS        \Package\DELETE DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS   -
OnError 12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOC_INFO:Error: The version of ODBC Destination is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOC_INFO   EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOC_INFO (SSIS.Pipeline)   \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOC_INFO  -
OnError 12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOC_INFO:Error: The version of ODBC Source is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOC_INFO   EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOC_INFO (SSIS.Pipeline)   \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOC_INFO  -
OnError 12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOCATIONS:Error: The version of ODBC Destination is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOCATIONS  EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOCATIONS (SSIS.Pipeline)  \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOCATIONS -
OnError 12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOCATIONS:Error: The version of ODBC Source is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOCATIONS  EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOCATIONS (SSIS.Pipeline)  \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH STOCK_LOCATIONS -
OnError 12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_LINES:Error: The version of ODBC Destination is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_LINES   EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_LINES (SSIS.Pipeline)   \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_LINES  -
OnError 12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_LINES:Error: The version of ODBC Source is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_LINES   EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_LINES (SSIS.Pipeline)   \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_LINES  -
OnError 12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_HDR:Error: The version of ODBC Destination is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_HDR EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_HDR (SSIS.Pipeline) \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_HDR    -
OnError 12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_HDR:Error: The version of ODBC Source is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_HDR EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_HDR (SSIS.Pipeline) \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH PURCHORD_HDR    -
OnError 12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_LINES:Error: The version of ODBC Destination is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_LINES  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_LINES (SSIS.Pipeline)  \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_LINES -
OnError 12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_LINES:Error: The version of ODBC Source is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_LINES  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_LINES (SSIS.Pipeline)  \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_LINES -
OnError 12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_COSTS:Error: The version of ODBC Destination is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_COSTS  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_COSTS (SSIS.Pipeline)  \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_COSTS -
OnError 12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_COSTS:Error: The version of ODBC Source is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_COSTS  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_COSTS (SSIS.Pipeline)  \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS_COSTS -
OnError 12/10/2016 12:59:36 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS:Error: The version of ODBC Source is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS    EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS (SSIS.Pipeline)    \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS   -
OnError 12/10/2016 12:59:35 PM  EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS:Error: The version of ODBC Destination is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS    EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS (SSIS.Pipeline)    \Package\EXO TO DATA_WH INWARDS_GOODS   -
OnInformation   12/10/2016 12:59:34 PM  The validate operation has started. Transact-SQL stored procedure           -
```

I'm hoping someone can help me with what is going wrong.

I've made sure that both the 32bit and 64bit drivers are installed to the ODBC manager.  I've also tried valiadating the package in SSMS with 32-bit runtime ticked.  No luck whatsoever.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

MSSQL v12.0.4459.0, running on Win Server 2012

MySQL v5.5.52-0, running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Looking logs you are using some custom component (Attunity) that dll is not available at on you server..

error "ODBC Destination;Connector for Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) by Attunity; Attunity Ltd"

Answer (score 0):

Found this online for anyone thats interested.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/30010ea5-e9e5-43f0-920e-dc981f20dcff/ssdt-2015-140603060-gives-odbc-component-missing-for-attunity-when-deployed-to-mssql-2014?forum=ssdt

My issue was related to how my projects were being compiled when they were being deployed.  You need to chose the version of SQL server you are deploying to so that it the outputted package is compatibile.